# Sleuth Header X-B3-TraceId value get Regenerated even if passed to the Service Request as Header In Bluemix

Tags: java, spring, ibm-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I would like my service consumers pass the TraceId as Header Param with name X-B3-TraceId and valid 128 bits Hex String that shall get propagated in further path down the line and indeed service will return same Sleuth Trace Id back to caller. I have used Spring Cloud Sleuth added Custom Filter and Span Extractor in order to put in in Service Response.

The Entire set up works well in my local when App is deployed in Embedded tomcat, however when same App is deployed in Bluemix then The Response does not have same Sleuth Trace Id which was passed in Request.

Is there any known such defect and workaround for this problem when Sleuth is used in IBM Bluemix Cloud Foundry ?

If it is, could you please advise how to proceed.

I have created Demo Project in following location: https://github.com/imram/sleuthHeaderIssue

```
Please Run the Micro Service locally.    
URL: localhost:9090/hello?name=Ram
Header:
    X-B3-TraceId:d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3ee52

Service will return:
    HELLORam
    Header:
    Content-Length →8
    Content-Type →text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Date →Thu, 11 Jan 2018 01:38:48 GMT
    X-Application-Context →application:9090
    X-B3-TraceId →d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3ee52

    Note Trace Id is same in RQ and RS.

Deploy Same Service in IBM Bluemix:
    URL: https://sleuth-header-demo.mybluemix.net/hello?name=Ram .
    Header
    X-B3-TraceId:d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3ee52

    Response:
       HELLORam
       Header:
       Connection →Keep-Alive
       Content-Type →text/plain;charset=UTF-8
       Date →Thu, 11 Jan 2018 01:38:30 GMT
       Transfer-Encoding →chunked
       X-Application-Context →sleuth-header-demo:bluemix:0
       X-B3-Traceid →b896d05d9f0ae105
       X-Backside-Transport →OK OK
       X-Global-Transaction-ID →2714561407

 See the Trace Id(X-B3-Traceid) got ignore what was present in 
 Request and got Regenerated as b896d05d9f0ae105
```

Comment: I'm not an expert with Bluemix but most likely in Bluemix there's some component that (go router or sth) that takes part in the communication and is not traced. THat means that it ignores the tracing headers and doesn't propagate them. But that's just my hunch.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak  Thaks Marcin. In order to check if your above comment make sense, I added a down line call from the /hello API that makes another call to one more resource in same service. As you mentioned even for the down line call as well even though which is happening through the RestTemplate that is intercepting Sluth Span, in blue mix deplored app, it is generating the new Span for each such component. I am surprised if anyone has used Sleuth for distributed traceability in Bluemix Apps. I have approached some of Bluemix SMEs to assist here further.

Comment: Here is the solution I got. In order to make it work in Bluemix, I need to pass TraceId as well as SpanId both headers together in Request.

Comment: You always need to pass both values. All the `X-B3` headers must be propagated to make distributed tracing work properly.

Comment: Result as expected after passing both values:
URL: https://sleuth-header-demo.mybluemix.net/hello?name=Ram
Headers:
X-B3-TraceId:d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3bb22
X-B3-SpanId:ce5f844337f3ee88
Response:
Header:
X-B3-Spanid →ce5f844337f3ee88
X-B3-Traceid →d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3bb22
Body: Welcome There!!

App Logs:
[-,d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3bb22,ce5f844337f3ee88,true] [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.s.SleuthHeaderController : Ram Forwarding to Home 
[-,d61436368bae3c12ce5f844337f3bb22,ee27e23e5f565eb0,true][nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.s.SleuthHeaderController : Call is at Home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to pass tracing headers. All the X-B3 headers must be propagated to make distributed tracing work properly.

Comment: Could you provide the link/list with all needed headers?

Comment: You can check this class https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/brave/src/main/java/brave/propagation/B3Propagation.java for more information

Answer (score 3):

below 2 conditions are required:

1. both X-B3-TraceId and X-B3-SpanId are required in header
2. the value of X-B3 variables should be valid.

```
    @GetMapping("/async")
    public String helloSleuthAsync() throws InterruptedException {       
        return "success, traceId:" + MDC.get("X-B3-TraceId");
    }
```

e.g.

condition 2 is matched:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/async' \
--header 'X-B3-TraceId: d61436368bae3c12' \
--header 'X-B3-SpanId: ce5f844337f3ee88'

response: success, traceId:d61436368bae3c12
```

condition 2 is not matched:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/async' \
--header 'X-B3-TraceId: marius' \
--header 'X-B3-SpanId: marius'

response:success, traceId:4faae9c09822cf72
```

Comment: see the difference between 2 examples above, compare the value of X-B3-TraceId in headers and the traceId printed in response.